# Blur event include submit button too /jquery

Tags: jquery, button, submit, blur

When i used blur event out of input text field, it include all page, but submit button too. So how to avoid that the blur event do not include submit button?

Here is html code:

```
<form>
   <input type="text" value="EMAIL ADDRESS_" id="text" />
   <input type="submit" val="" id="submit" />
</form>
```

and script:

```
$('form input[type!=submit]').focus(function(){
     $(this).val("");
     });
$('form input[type!=submit]').blur(function(){
     if(this.value==""){
     $(this).val("EMAIL ADDRESS_");
  }
});
```

I take this code from my previous question, but it doesn't work.Blur event still include submit button

Comment: If all you are doing is updating the placeholder in the text field and if you are using HTML5, you should use the `placeholder` attribute so specify that text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think instead of avoiding one field from the selection, you should better specify the items to be considered for selection. Otherwise if someone / you, in the futue may add a new element to the form and you may be wondering where this behaviour (of blur and focus) is coming from for the "just now added element" !

```
$(function(){
 $("form input[type='text']").focus(function(){
       $(this).val("");
     });
 $("form input[type='text']").blur(function(){
     if(this.value==""){
        $(this).val("EMAIL ADDRESS_");
      }
  });
});
```

Note that you are still  targeting **all input fields which is of type text**. So if possible try to make it more specific by applying a class name to those elements and use that as the selector. Or you may use the **id** of the element as well.

```
$("form #yourElemntId").focus(function(){
   //do stuff
});
```

Comment: This is the answer that i need, tnx.

Comment: I think this solution is good too:

 var setTimer = { timer: null }
        $('input,select').blur(function () {
            setTimer.timer = setTimeout(function () {
               $('#text').val('text');
            }, 200);
        });

        $('input,select').focus(function () {
            setTimer.timer = setTimeout(function () {
                $('#text').val('');
            }, 200);
        });

        $("#submit").click(function () {
            clearTimeout(setTimer.timer);
            //do something
        });

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is almost good, you are just missing the quotes between `submit`

```
$("form input[type!='submit']").focus(function(){
     $(this).val("");
     });
$("form input[type!='submit']").blur(function(){
     if(this.value==""){
     $(this).val("EMAIL ADDRESS_");
  }
});
```